# Al ha-eitz for flavorings/garnishes

Tags: blessing, food, fruits

Let's say I eat a salad that has a few pomegranate seeds sprinkled on top. Do I make al Ha-eitz afterward? Do I then make borei n'fashos, or does the al ha-eitz cover the whole salad?

What if it's [pomegranate-flavored tea](http://www.wteashop.com/Wissotzky-Tea-Pomegranate-Tea-Box-of-20-bags_p_102.html)?

-

MOTIVE: I asked a rabbi this shailo when I had this salad. He wasn't sure.

POTENTIAL ISSUES INVOLVED: 1) Quantity. I learned that "any amount" of the seven species necessitates an al ha-eitz, but I can't remember if this is strictly correct--nor whether one would then need to make a bracha acharona on the "main" part of the food. 2) Someone recently told me, probably incorrectly, that al ha-eitz is only made if the food actually came from the Land of Israel. This is wrong, right? 3) For the tea question, the processed nature of the pomegranate flavoring may affect whether one makes an al ha-eitz. Does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response to the POTENTIAL ISSUES INVOLVED:

1) Amount of food (and time) on which one makes an after-brocho. See [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bracha_Achrona).

> One is only obligated to make a Bracha Achrona on a food if one eats
>   a Kezayit of food in Kedi Achilat Pras.

See the article for definition
of the terms but in short Kezayit = 27 to 33 ccs. Kedi Achilat Pras =
up to 7.5 minutes.

2) Only from Eretz Yisroel?

> The Bracha Achrona for grapes, figs, pomegranate, olives, and dates is
>   Bracha Achat Mein Shalosh with the insert of Al HaEtz VeAl Pri HaEtz. 
>   Tur 208:1 writes that the fruit of the seven species with which Israel
>   was praised have Bracha Achrona of Bracha Mein Shalosh. S”A 208:1
>   agrees.

From the expression of the Tur, we see that the fruit does not have to come from Eretz Yisroel. Where the produce does comes from  Eretz Yisroel,  the end of the [blessing is adjusted](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/32-Which-Bracha-Achrona-to-Say.html)  to note that.

3) Pomegranate flavoured tea.

The blessings on fruit juices (other than grape) are Shehakol and Borei Nefashos (see [here for apple juice](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot_On_Foods_That_Start_With_The_Letter_A) ) . A flavoured tea will attract the same blessings.
Regarding making an after-blessing on hot drinks see [this](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bracha_Achrona#Bracha_Achrona_on_coffee_or_tea) as to whether a blessing is said at all.

Comment: Support for this answer (specifically Nos. 1 and 3): http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Print.aspx?HalachaID=2403

Comment: Let's say I do eat a kezayis of pomegranate seeds in the required time. Will the Al Ha-eitz cover my entire salad or just the pomegranate? That is, do I need a separate Borei N'fashos for the lettuce? (also, for the bracha achrona, should I be making both Ha-Eitz and ha-adamah on this salad, or just a ha-eitz?)  Pardon my ignorance and thanks

Comment: Can you bring a source that even a food from the seven species becomes shehakol if liquefied? (I believe you, just would love to see a source if possible)

Comment: Pomegranate juice:
See [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/250741-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A5-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D); we follow the Terumas HaDeshen brocho is shehakol.
See [here2](http://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/10-08-15-02/) after some discussion - brocho for juice drunk from a cup (and not a spoon – see the discussion there) is shehakol.

Comment: After making an al-haeitz on the pomegranate seeds, does one then make borei n'fashos on the salad? Yes, right?